# Display image returned by aspx GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, image

I'm trying to display an image returned by an aspx page like this

```
<asp:Image ID="ButtonImage" runat="server" 
         Width="200" 
         Height="113" 
         BackColor="LightGray" 
         ImageUrl="/Editor/OpenMedia.aspx?path=336!TestImage.jpg"/>
```

OpenMedia.aspx

```
public partial class OpenMedia : MemberPage
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string path = Request.QueryString["path"];
       HASFile file = new HASFile(path);

       HASConnection con = new HASConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HASUrl"]);
       HASReader reader = new HASReader(con);

       reader.getFile(file, Response.OutputStream);
       Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
    }
}
```

When I look at the response with fiddler the image is returned correctly and it works correctly in Firefox but not in IE. How come this isn't working with IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that some of the images I tested with where corrupt in some way that internet explorer couldn't solve. Firefox could display the images even if they where corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the sequence:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";  

   string path = Request.QueryString["path"]; 
   HASFile file = new HASFile(path); 
   HASConnection con = new HASConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HASUrl"]); 
   HASReader reader = new HASReader(con); 

   reader.getFile(file, Response.OutputStream); 
}
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference at all.